# using joomla (or even just PHP), how would you obfuscate a PDF filename?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a file, call it secret.pdf, that I offer for download. However, I would like to keep it from having a URL that can be copied / pasted or typed out like www.website.com/pdf/secret.pdf (no fishing for files!).

For instance, user A clicks on the link, and gets kgsjgldsg.pdf. User B clicks the same link, but gets asadsfsefaw.pdf. The point is, a random filename is used to reference the same file, secret.pdf.

Ive googled php file obfuscator, and joomla filename obfuscator, and have had no luck. Any ideas or a pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `GET` variable based on time, that is valid for 1 minute (should be enough).

So your request would be `/pdf/getPDF.php?key=xxxxxxxxx`

Make `key` a salted hash based on the current time on your server, for instance the closest number dividable by 5 (when it's 17:17 you'd use 17:15, etc).

Then generations the 'current' hash on your `getPDF.php` file, and if it is the same, then stream your pdf.

This will NOT stop people from using the link, but the link will only be valid for 5 minutes.

Addendum: You should make sure the pdf is not reachable from outside, but only readable for your pdf-streaming php-file (e.g. outside your `/var/www` or equivalent directory)

Comment: Still leaves a window open. Better yet is to record the generated key value in a database and invalidate/delete the key the moment the download script is called. That way it can be left "open" as long as possible, and self closes as soon as the download commences.

Comment: Completely agree, but I don't know if it is that big a problem to leave the window open. It's not an issue of security, because the pdf can be  shared anyway: I don't think you are fighting a real problem here, but theoretically you are right :D

Comment: yeah, and I guarantee Ill have a user that clicks it more than once, and the second time around (when it throws a 'file not found') they will have a stroke. Better to leave a smallish window I think this time. Still, good to know its an option.

Comment: "Current" Hash? What if the getPDF-Link is generated at 17:19:59 ? To solve this, you would need to check the last 2 hashes in getPDF.php (e.g. 17:20 and 17:15 if the current time is 17:21).

Comment: a minor (from technical) but important point! But you should be able to work around that issue. Nevertheless good you've pointed this out :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative is to store the pdf file 1 level up from your public_html web folder on your hosting account. You can then use a full path to deliver the file to the user as a download. This way no one can access the file as it is not available on your website. Only the code on your site knows where the file is. I do this for a number of components, see code below relating to Joomla:

```
    $file = '/home/domain/files/secret.pdf'
    $filesize = filesize(file );
    JResponse::setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    JResponse::setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'Binary');
    JResponse::setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
    JResponse::setHeader('Content-Length', $filesize);
    echo JFile::read($file);
```